# C# convert comma separated string to dynamic type

Tags: c#

How do I convert a CSV string to an array of a type that is only known at run time. Say I have 2 array fields in my class of different types declared as `int[] intArray` and `string[] strArray`. I want a single function where I pass in 2 parameters the field name and CSV string. I can use the `...; FieldInfo f =... ; Type t = f.FieldType.GetElementType();` But what I can't do is declare `List<t>` because t is a variable and not a type. I saw one post suggesting `csv.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ChangeType(s, t)).ToArray()` but this comes out as an object array not an int or string array; another post saying `...; var list = (IList) Activate.CreatInstance(...)`, which is fine that I can call `list.Add(...)` but then what do I do as I need an Array of t.

Comment: have you considered using a csv library?

Comment: Use string.Join(separator, array)

Comment: Maybe you should check Linq To CSV on GitHub.

Comment: I’ll ask, is this a personal project or something where you can’t use someone else’s code? Also, splitting by the comma (`,`) is not a good idea because some flavors of CSV allow escaping it, and some allow quoted strings. For example, a good CSV parser will allow parsing of `foo,"bar",foo\,bar` as `["foo", "bar", "foo,bar"]`. Yours will (I’m assuming) parse it as `["foo", "\"bar\"", "foo\\", "bar"]`. Basically, there’s no “specification” for CSV to follow, so you never know what kind of data you’re gonna get.

Comment: How do you intend to _use_ the array? If you don't know the type at compile-time then an `object[]` or a `List<object>` may be sufficient. If you have a specific use-case where that does not work for you, then add that to your question so an appropriate solution can be found.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a nuget package to do this parsing. [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) has an example of how to [deserialize to a given type](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records).

Comment: Thank you for this, in my own time I will check out this CsvHelper class as no doubt my solution below is probably reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I have bitten the bullet on this one and so will have to update my code if I need a new type like array of float numbers say is required but this suffices for what I need today, and I do agree with the other mentions about CSV what if my values had commas say addresses and came in as "\"12 George St, Sydney\",\"200 Sussex St, Sydney\"" then I would have to consider advanced CSV however again this is all I need for today.

```
class SetPropertyByName
{
    public object this[string fieldName]
    {
        set
        {
            FieldInfo field = this.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (null != field)
            {
                if (field.FieldType.IsArray && value is String)
                {
                    string newValue = (string)value;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue))
                        value = null;
                    else
                    {
                        var conversionType = field.FieldType.GetElementType();
                        if (conversionType == typeof(string))
                        {
                            value = newValue.Split(',').ToArray();
                        }
                        else if (conversionType == typeof(int))
                        {
                            value = newValue.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();
                        }                         
                    }
                    field.SetValue(this, value);
                }
                else
                    field.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(value, field.FieldType));
            }
        }
    }
}
```